# Remove div php - part of string

Tags: php, html

I want to remove part of string between two html tags. I have something like this:

```
$variable = "This is something that I don't want to delete<blockquote>This is I want to delete </blockquote>";
```

the problem is that the string between blockquote tag is changing, and its need to be deleted,  no matter what it is. Anyone now how?

Comment: Take a look at regex expressions.

Comment: Do not take a look at regex expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex are not the best thing to parse html string, you should take a look at [Simple HTML dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or the php [DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.domdocument.php).

If you still want to use a regex in this case it will be for example :

```
$variable = preg_replace('/<blockquote>.+<\/blockquote>/siU', '', $variable);
```

[Test it there.](http://ideone.com/B9SWaC)

Comment: This will not remove `<blockquote></blockquote>`. Also since you're just deleting the text the parentheses are unnecessary

Comment: This will remove <blockquote></blockquote> see the Ideone link...

Comment: I solve it with DOMDocument class. Thanks...

Comment: @soyuka no it won't: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/43d-y4n. The `.+` needs to be `.*` or it won't remove the *literal* html `<blockquote></blockquote>` only `<blockquote>sometext</blockquote>`. Also you forgot the ungreedy modifier, now it will remove all of `<blockquote>This I want removed.</blockquote> This I do not want removed <blockquote>This I want removed.</blockquote>`

Comment: @dtech Corrected, you're right about the ungreedy modifier but still it's really not the best way for parsing DOM elements ! I'd add that he had a string between the `blockquotes` so `.+` does work in his case, and he didn't ask for a global way of doing it !

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions, but this is by no means fail-safe and should only be used in trivial cases. A better way is to use a full-fledged HTML parser.

```
<?php
$str = preg_replace('#<blockquote>.*</blockquote>#siU', '', $str);
?>
```

Comment: this just remove `<blockquote>` tags...I need it to remove text between those tags, along with tags.

Comment: Change `'$1'` to `''`: http://php.net/preg_replace

Answer (score 0):

please try using regex in this way

```
<?php
$variable = "This is something that I don't want to delete<blockquote>This is I want to delete </blockquote>";
$str = preg_replace('#(<blockquote>).*?(</blockquote>)#', '$1$2', $variable);
print($str);
?>
```